# Blue prism "The collection has no current rows"

Tags: collections, blueprism

In Blue Prism, after traversing the rows of collection using a loop, if any column is referenced to take first value of that column using CollectionName.ColmName, I am getting error saying "The collection has no current rows." although row count of collection is greater than 1. 
How can I set the cursor back to the first row or any other way to get first value of a column?

Answer (score 3):

Your misunderstanding lies in the details (emphasis mine):

> Collection has no *current* row

After looping over a collection, you'll notice that the collection in the page will simply show the number of rows currently contained within a collection instead of the usual "Row *X* of *Y*". This state indicates that Blue Prism's internal pointer isn't looking at one row in particular.

Once you've reached the end of a collection within a loop, you could use the beginning Loop stage to reset the internal counter to 1

I'm includinig a GIF demonstration below to help illustrate my test case:

[image: GIF demonstration]

Comment: Thanks for you answer. 
I got your point. Infact, I am also using a loop to take the pointer to first row thinking this as temporary solution. Do we have any other option to fix this or this is the ideal way ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use “Read Collection Field” from “Utility – Collection Manipulation” VBO. This action allows you to get value from any column & any row from your collection. As an input you need to provide:

1. Collection
2. Field Name (Column Name)
3. Row Index

If you don’t have this VBO you can find it in your Blue Prism installation folder in VBO subfolder.